# Creating a string in R with " in it

Tags: r

I am trying to get text given between “ ” to make a string. But because string has two “ already in it, I am not able to do so.

```
?jql=filter%20=%20"Plan%20Standup%20-%20Mutual-SA"
```

When I am trying to input , it is giving me an error.

```
Input <- "?jql=filter%20=%20"Plan%20Standup%20-%20Mutual-SA""
```

I tried many escape characters, but always I got an error message.

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "input <- "?jql=filter%20=%20"Plan"
```

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: There is a double quote inside it.  So, use single quote at the end i.e. `Input <- '?jql=filter%20=%20"Plan%20Standup%20-%20Mutual-SA'`

Comment: try using single quote

Comment: Or escape the internal double quote  `"This is a \"quoted\" string"`

Comment: It worked!!! using single quote.Thanks guys.

Comment: @akrun please add the answer, to avoid questions answered in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the string, there is already a double quote.  So, we can wrap it with single quotes

```
Input <- '?jql=filter%20=%20"Plan%20Standup%20-%20Mutual-SA'
cat(Input, "\n")
#?jql=filter%20=%20"Plan%20Standup%20-%20Mutual-SA
```

Answer (score 0):

"Escape" the character like this

```
a <- "\""
```